# App crashes on load only while profile is set to debug

Tags: xamarin.ios

When I try deploy an app with the build type set to debug the app is deployed but crashes straight away.
If I try using the release mode the app is deployed and works fine.

I have tried cleaning the project and redeploying however that doesnt seem to help.

I have taken a look at the crash log but it doesnt make sense to me.

What do I need to do to get to the issue of what's causing the app to crash while trying to debug?

Comment: Is there anything suspicious in the build output? Is your project confuguration (iOS build submenu) consistent between Debug and Release builds?

Comment: if nothing shows in the XS log, you can get valuable info about the crash from the device log (access it through Xcode>Organizer>Devices>Device Log )

Comment: Please post the crash report too. It might make sense to other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint in the Main.cs

If there isn´t a try catch build one around UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate"); and put a breakpoint inside the catch.

From there you can go back in the stacktrace to find the cause.